# How to input more methods in document.getElementById by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I don't find the problem in my code.
I would like to specif more methods in the element.

I need to apply the `toUpperCase()` and `.slice()` methods about `document.getElementById(id)` and put in variable. but appears undefined.
Can you help me?

```
<div id="app"></div>
<form id="formulario">
    <p>Nome do Autor: <input id="name" type="text"/></p>
    <p>Título: <input id="title" type="text"/></p>
    <p>Número da edição: <input id="edition" type="number"/></p>
    <p>Local de publicação: <input id="local" type="text"/></p>
    <p>Nome da Editora: <input id="publisher" type="text"/></p>
    <p>Ano da publicação: <input id="age" type="number"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send"/></p>
    Pelas normas da ABNT ficará assim: 
    <p id='textABNT'></p>
</form>

<script>
    var form = document.getElementById("formulario");
    var nome = document.getElementById("name");
    var titulo = document.getElementById("title");
    var edicao = document.getElementById("edition");
    var localpub = document.getElementById("local");
    var editora = document.getElementById("publisher");
    var ano = document.getElementById("age");
    var sobrenome = document.getElementById(
        "name"
        .split(" ")
        .slice(-1)
        .toString()
        .toUpperCase()
    );

    form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
      // impede o envio do form
      e.preventDefault();

      document.getElementById("textABNT").innerHTML =
        sobrenome.value +
        " " +
        nome.value[0] +
        ". " +
        " " +
        titulo.value +
        ": " +
        edicao.value +
        ". ed. " +
        localpub.value +
        ": " +
        editora.value +
        ", " +
        ano.value;
    });

</script>
```

Comment: `"name"
        .split(" ")
        .slice(-1)
        .toString()
        .toUpperCase()` comes out as 'NAME' for me

Comment: undefined . Because id="name" is a input text.

Comment: <script>
var sobrenome = 
  "name" 
    .split(" ")
    .slice(-1)
    .toString()
    .toUpperCase()
;
</script>

<HTML>
<p>Nome do Autor: <input id="name" type="text"></p>

Comment: You want to get the text from an input whos id is 'name', and THEN you want to split that text, and uppercase it?

Comment: Yes, and slice(-1). because I need the last word in the input.

Comment: Looks like you need a closing bracket `)` after `"name"`...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is more like

```
var sobrenome = document.getElementById("name"); 
var sobrenomeText =  sobrenome.value.split(" ")
                      .slice(-1)
                      .toString()
                      .toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Thansk,
but when i put 
document.getElementById("textABNT").innerHTML =
    sobrenomeText.value

Return me undefined.

Comment: `document.getElementById("textABNT").innerHTML = sobrenomeText;` sobrenomeText is a variable pointing to a string, so there is no `.value`

Comment: Ok, but when I remove .value
I don't have the return.
How to return this variable?
I need to return this value on the HTML.

Comment: I don't have any idea what you're talking about.